# Error in UseMethod("sentiment") : no applicable method for 'sentiment' applied to an object of class "factor"

Tags: r, text-mining, sentiment-analysis

I am a newbie at R and im trying conduct a sentiment analysis with sentimentr.

I am trying to analyse data from a csv file:

```
setwd("C:/Users/Utilizador/Desktop/teste")
df <- read.csv("comments.csv", sep = ";")
library(sentimentr)
df$sentimentscore <- 0
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
   df[i,]$sentimentscore <- mean(as.numeric(sentiment(df[i,1])$sentiment))
}
```

However, I get this error

> Error in UseMethod("sentiment") :     no applicable method for
>   'sentiment' applied to an object of class "factor"

Comment: In the code the `as.numeric` is applied on each row.  It is already .  It is already a vector and there is no 'sentiment' column.  I am guessing that you need just `mean(as.numeric(as.character(df$sentiment)))` as `mean` is vectorized (`as.numeric(as.character` - in case the column type is `factor`).  Without a small reproducioble example with `dput`, it is difficult to know the structure or test

Comment: What is `class(df[,1])`? If it's a factor, then try to determine why was it read in as a factor. Also, can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`.

Comment: My guess? Use `read.csv("comments.csv", sep=";", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)` (or just `read.csv2("comments.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`, as it defaults to `sep=";"`).